# Invoke-Restmethod powershell in Azure Devops - strange powershell errors

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I am using this invoke-restmethod so I can get a token so I can do some sql work. the variables come from Azure Key Vault. I have tried to write the variables as

```
$($SPNAppid)
$SPNAppid
${$SPNAppid} etc
```

Here is the code :

> $request = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri
> "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${$TenantId}"/oauth2/token" -Body
> @{ resource="https://database.windows.net/";
> grant_type="client_credentials"; client_id=${$SPNAppid};
> client_secret=${$SPNValue} } -ContentType
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Getting this error below. What is the best way to do this - whatever i do i am getting the errors below.

```
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to 
delimit the name.
At C:\agent01_2\_work\_temp\b3f54d23-b7b6-4cc3-96ec-8b4b534be571.ps1:20 char:319
+ ... ervicePrincipalKey } -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
+                                                                         ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted, has an extra `"` and given the ambiguity of the long line I would suggest to use splatting like this :

```
$header = @{
    "Content-type"  = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
}

$body = @{ 
    resource      = "https://database.windows.net/"
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = $SPNAppid
    client_secret = $SPNValue
} 

$params = @{
    Method      = 'Post'
    Uri         = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TenantId)/oauth2/token"
    Body        = $body
    ContentType = $header
}

$request = Invoke-RestMethod @params
```

I do not think the API call would work this way, usually clientId etc. are part of the URL, you can read more about it here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow